# Are transitive dependencies built into a default (statically linked) final Go program binary?

Tags: go, linker, dependencies, static-linking

In the `Go` programming language, assuming a default "statically linked" build, I'm wondering if, for example in the case I have 2 modules in `go.mod` but 50 in `go.sum`, (assume 25 transitive for each of the 2 in my `go.mod`), are all 50 of the modules listed in `go.sum` actually going to be built into my program's output binary? That is, does `go build` fetch those transitive dependencies and compile them all, statically linking them into the output binary? If so, Does it do so for the entire modules or only the portions actually referenced by my program?

Does it behave in the same manner for vendored dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

Go will only build and link the packages actually referenced by the parts of your program being built (including transitive references).

As you noted, the `go.sum` file may be larger--possibly much larger--than the set of packages your project actually requires in order to build (on your system, with the selected configuration). Among other reasons, the `go.sum` (and `go.mod`) file will contain references to packages which are only needed under certain configurations.